# How to change maximum size of Google Group file attachments?

Tags: gmail, google-groups, attachment

I looked for this over the net and on support.google.com but found nothing.

I've got a Google group and if I send a mail with a size more than 8MB I'll receive a failure message due to max size limitation. According to Google help I can change the maximum file size in group settings up to 25MB. But I couldn't find anything to help me with this for my group, also I didn't find anything in my group settings.

How can I change the maximum file size of attachments for the group?

Comment: I'm not seeing any setting in the new Google Groups interface. Is the help page you're looking at outdated? Can you provide a link?

Comment: Well, it is on the right top section of the page. Exactly like your gmail UI. Also it is at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!groupsettings/YOURGROUP/information

Comment: There's no setting to control the size limit. I have the same problem. Emails bounce if attachment is larger than 8MB (not 25MB).

Answer (score 4):

Maximum size for attachment is 25MB. Exceeding the limit will bounce back with an error to the sender and fails to send to the group.

For attachments exceeding 25MB,

1. **Google Drive is the best** as Google Groups and Gmail can be accessed with no additional login info which is obviously very secured.
2. This can also be done with other file hosting sites like mediafire,
   Dropbox, sendspace, fileserve, filesanywhere, AmazonCloudDrive,
   rapidgator, zippyshare etc. But these sites may need to sign up for free to upload the files into your website account.
3. In any of the sites (Google Drive or other sites), You need to upload the file and set the attachment privacy to everyone.
4. Finally, share the link of the file by copy & pasting into your google groups.

If the recipients are very few and iff you have the list of emails, 
then you may also send emails with attachments to each member personally (upto 25MB only).

Google Groups doesn’t support bigger sizes for attachments. To my knowledge, it allows a maximum of 25MB. I think the upload size limit it the same. If you try to upload any attachments exceeding the file size limit, they will not be posted in the group. And the error mail will be bounced back to the sender only.

Comment: Do you have any link to support your claims? [Groups administrator FAQ](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167085?hl=en) says only about 25 MB limit per single message an there seems to be not even a trace of 4 MB limit per single attachment.

Comment: Please try out sending an email in these two ways:
1. with less than 4mb and 2. another email with more than 4mb to any google group, and you will be able to check whether the group members if they can receive and access your email/post.

Comment: Used to be a 4MB limit, back when Groups was first created. Saw the FAQ, then found this, haven't found the setting claimed in the FAQ as yet.

Answer (score 1):

The current editions have a fixed limit for message size including attachments, in other words, there is no way to change the limit.

There are two editions,

1. "Regular", https://groups.google.com
2. Google Groups for Business, `https://groups.google.com/a/YOURDOMAIN`, G Suite Admins should enabled this for their users, also they could set a custom URL to access this app.