# What is an exact limit of attachments that can be sent in a single message to Google Groups?

Tags: google-groups

Groups administrator FAQ [says](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167085?hl=en#limits) (emphasis mine):

> Yes, the maximum size limit for messages sent to a group is **25 MB**, including attachments (the normal Gmail limit). Group owners or managers can edit specific groups to set lower size limits. The default size for a message sent in Google Groups is **25 MB**.

A moment ago I've tried to send a message to my own group, having four lines of plain text and a total of two attachments (PDF files) -- 13 009 kB + 3 427 kB (16 MB according to Windows). I was blocked from doing so with an error message that total size of message exceeds group limit.

**What am I missing? Where is the remaining 9+ MB to *really* exceed mentioned group limit?**

(*I'm group creator / owner / admin and for sure I haven't set lower limit, simply due to the fact, that I don't even know, where such limit can be configured in group management panel*)

Some side-notes and research effects:

**1**. [An answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/90174/21486) to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/35894/21486) says something about 4 MB limits per file, which is something totally new for me. Is this still an active limit (question asked in 2012, but answered this year) as I don't find even a trace of 4 MB limit in [Groups administrator FAQ](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167085?hl=en)?

This would fit to my case as one of the attachments has 13 MB of size. But, again, I don't know, if that 4-MB-per-file limit really exists as this is something new to me.

**2**. Four years old [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/35894/how-to-change-maximum-size-of-google-group-file-attachments#comment26689_35894) to the very same question says that I can use an URL like this:

```
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!groupsettings/YOURGROUPNAME/information
```

However, after using it (with replaced correct group name) I can't find any size-limits-related setting in neither this or any other section of my groups configuration.

Comment: The administrator FAQ linked is for Google Groups for Business (for G Suite accounts) but he URL from the "old comment" looks to be for Google Groups (consumer edition). Are you using the Google Groups or Google Groups for Business?

Comment: Related threads in Google Help Forums
[Posting of 10MB file to google groups results in limits exceeded message](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/UnRz10-R3xY), 
[How to change the attachment size in message in Google groups](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/qDjH9S6gGbE)

Comment: @Rubén I'm using "regular" Google Groups. However the problem discussed here is about per-attachment size limit which isn't mentioned in neither of these two FAQs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

According to several posts, the limit for individual file attachments is 4MB<sup>[1](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/apps/4NYpN8YIw_k/U1Fni-pdrbIJ),[2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/90174/88163)</sup>. There is no official documentation about this.

## Explanation

It's usual that users get confused by the way that Google use the term "groups". as there are:

- Contacts groups in Gmail and Google Contacts
- Groups created from the G Suite admin console
- Google Groups, http://groups.google.com
- Google Groups for Business, `http://groups.google.com/a/yourdomain.com`

The referred [Groups Administrator FAQ](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167085?hl=en) by the OP is about groups created from the G Suite admin console and about Google Groups for Business.

While Google Groups for Business and Google Groups are very similar, some features and limits are not the same. I.E. a Google Group for Business group administrator could change the message size limit while a Google Groups group administrator can't.

The Official documentation for Google Groups could be found at http://support.google.com/groups. The official documentation for Google Groups for Business is included in the [G Suite Administrator Help](http://support.google.com/a/). Both editions are in scope of the [G Suit Help Forum - Google Groups Category](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/apps/google-groups-for-business).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple. Even though [Groups administrator FAQ](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167085?hl=en) says nothing about this, another limit of *up to 4 MB per each attachment* really exists, when posting to Google Groups.

Thus, example message posted to Google Groups with *10 files per up to 2 MB each* will be successfully posted, because neither official (25 MB per message) nor unofficial (4 MB per file) limit is exceeded in this scenario.

While another example message with *just 2 files but at least one having more than 4 MB* or with *as many files as you want having more than 25 MB total* will not be posted to Google Groups.

**EDIT**: *It seems that after only 24 hours since posting my answer is no longer valid. Yesterday, I've tried to post a message to Google Groups and failed on 2,7 MB and 3,1 MB attachments.*

*It looks like Google is intentionally not mentioning that per-attachment size limit in FAQ, because it seems to be changing / random / undetermined. Since each error message is heavily guarded by suggestions of using Google Drive instead, it may be part of strange Google marketing campaign.*

Comment: Did you receive an error message for the email with a 2,7 MB attachment?

Comment: @Rubén Yes, I did.

Comment: I just sent a message with an attachment ~3MB to a consumer group. It work fine.

Comment: Maybe it was some temporal problem? I don't know...